# how to access new created partition in container

Tags: docker, partitioning

I want to access new created partition in container with below actions but fail.

use `--device=` to mount a disk

```
docker run --privileged -d --device=/dev/vde:/dev/vde centos
```

use `parted` to create a new data partition

```
[root@cdba144bc679 ~]# lsblk                                              
lsblk: dm-0: failed to get device path
lsblk: dm-1: failed to get device path
lsblk: dm-0: failed to get device path
lsblk: dm-1: failed to get device path
lsblk: dm-2: failed to get device path
lsblk: dm-3: failed to get device path
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
vda    253:0    0  116G  0 disk 
├─vda1 253:1    0   52G  0 part /etc/hosts
└─vda2 253:2    0   64G  0 part 
vdb    253:16   0  400G  0 disk 
vdc    253:32   0  100G  0 disk 
vdd    253:48   0   10G  0 disk 
vde    253:64   0   10G  0 disk 
vdf    253:80   0   10G  0 disk 
vdg    253:96   0   10G  0 disk 
[root@cdba144bc679 ~]# parted -s /dev/vdg  mklabel gpt mkpart 1 ext4 1 2M
```

With `lsblk` can view:

```
[root@cdba144bc679 ~]# lsblk 
lsblk: dm-0: failed to get device path
lsblk: dm-1: failed to get device path
lsblk: dm-0: failed to get device path
lsblk: dm-1: failed to get device path
lsblk: dm-2: failed to get device path
lsblk: dm-3: failed to get device path
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
vda    253:0    0  116G  0 disk 
├─vda1 253:1    0   52G  0 part /etc/hosts
└─vda2 253:2    0   64G  0 part 
vdb    253:16   0  400G  0 disk 
vdc    253:32   0  100G  0 disk 
vdd    253:48   0   10G  0 disk 
vde    253:64   0   10G  0 disk 
vdf    253:80   0   10G  0 disk 
vdg    253:96   0   10G  0 disk 
└─vdg1 253:97   0    1M  0 part  <===
```

With `ls` can not access which means i can not use it:

```
[root@cdba144bc679 ~]# ll /dev/vdg*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 96 Nov  9 02:31 /dev/vdg
```

How can i access it?

Answer (score 2):

The current method that Docker uses to pass devices into a container won't allow you to dynamically pass a device after a container is created.

There have been a few discussions around this: [moby/moby #22563](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/22563) is a merged PR, but has discussion about further enhancements after the merge was done. Also [moby/moby #35359](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35359) is an open issue/feature request asking for device-related capabilities that would likely also serve your usecase.

The current workaround for right now would be to run `fdisk` in one container, and then run a new container that passes through all the block devices that are now available/created:

```
docker run --privileged -it --rm --device=/dev/vde:/dev/vde fdisk /dev/vde
```

Followed by:

```
docker run --privileged [...]\
    --device=/dev/vde:/dev/vde \
    --device=/dev/vde1:/dev/vde1 \
    --device=/dev/vde2:/dev/vde2 \
    centos
```